# Spring3: No mapping found for HTTP request

Tags: ajax, json, spring, rest

I'm sending the following request:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/ajax/rest/teamService/list HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/do/controlpanel
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: JSESSIONID=MMezuISPiL9aOEvxmoOKbUWI.undefined
```

My spring service xml maps /ajax to a controller.  This mapping should respond:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/*") 
public @ResponseBody JSONResponse team(@ModelAttribute("cpSession") ControlPanelSession sess, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

...

}
```

Other mappings in the same controller answer /ajax calls just fine.  For instance:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/isFNameOK", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String isFNameOK(@ModelAttribute("cpSession") ControlPanelSession sess, Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("fName") String fName) {

...

}
```

But apparently it's not, because I'm getting:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ajax/rest/teamService/list]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post any other mappings which are working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/rest/* will match `/rest/teamService`, but not `/rest/teamService/list`.

You could use /rest/** to match everything under the /rest path. However, you might prefer to use:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/{service}/{action}")
public @ResponseBody JSONResponse team(@PathVariable String service, @PathVariable String action, ...) {
```

Which will match your URL, and provide the wild-carded parts in your method body for further inspection.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!  I had no idea about **, and thought * would catch all of  it.  So I was completely stumped!  Thanks, Sean!